# How can I expand Sublime's language syntax understanding to incorporate custom syntax?

Tags: latex, sublimetext3

I know that sounds vague. Basically I just want Sublime to highlight custom syntax (color the text), just like it does with native syntax.

I am using Sublime to write LaTeX code. For those that don't know, LaTeX equations are typically enclosed by `\[` `\]`, e.g.

```
\[ E = m c^2 \]
```

Sublime understands that syntax and colors the enclosing code appropriately.

However, I use my custom defined command, `\eq{ ... }`, which wraps the `\[` `\]` functionality (so I can globally change some settings by just redefining the `\eq` definition). e.g.

```
\eq{ E = m c^2 }
```

I don't know anything about Sublime under the hood beyond basic key bindings. I want to expand Sublime's understanding of syntax to incorporate my custom command without wasting a ton of time digging through tutorials and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are mainly interested in the result and not in the reasoning, I will try to be as straight forward as I can.

The LaTeX syntax of Sublime Text will change in release `3119` and I would recommend to use that, if you want to change something.
Just download it from https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages and put the `LaTeX` folder into the folder, which opens when you select `Preferences >> Browse Packages...` in the Sublime Text menu.
Afterwards open the file `LaTeX.sublime-syntax` and search for `ensuremath` ([LaTeX.sublime-syntax#L498](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/LaTeX/LaTeX.sublime-syntax#L498)). Duplicate that part *(everything with a higher indent)* and change the command to the command you wish, e.g. in your example this would be `- match: '((\\)eq)(\{)'`.

Aside the new syntax removes the highlighting of math environments as strings, because this has lead to several problems.
I made a small entry in the [LaTeXTools wiki](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks#highlight-inside-math-environments) to explain, how you restore the highlight.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't mean to come across as anti-intellectual or lazy. I have a tendency to fall down rabbit holes when tweaking customizations and systems. By learning as little as possible here, I'm minimizing that chance